# Tensor Laplacian

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, tensors, general-relativity

For a general tensor $T_{\mu_1 \dots \mu_n}$ on a (pseudo-)Riemannian manifold, is it true that $$\Delta (T_{\mu_1 \dots \mu_n})= (\Delta T)_{\mu_1 \dots \mu_n}?$$

In general, it is not true that $(\nabla_{\nu}T)_{\mu}$ versus $\nabla_{\nu}(T_{\mu}),$ where $\nabla$ is the induced covariant derivative.

However, the coordinate formula given in [this article](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TensorLaplacian.html) seems to imply that equality does hold for the Laplacian.

**Attempt at a solution:**

If I consider the simplest case where $T$ is a $(1,0)$ vector field, then

$$\Delta (T_{\mu}) = \Delta (T(dx^{\mu})) = \Delta T (dx^{\mu})+ 2 \nabla^{\lambda} T \nabla_{\lambda} (dx^{\mu}) + T(\Delta (dx^{\mu})).$$ So it would suffice to show that the second and third term on the right hand side vanish. However, I don't see why they should...

Comment: What does the notations $\nabla (T_\mu)$ means (and the similar one for the laplacians)?

Comment: Sorry, I should have written $(\nabla_{\nu}T)_{\mu}$ versus $\nabla_{\nu}(T_{\mu}).$ The first expression denotes the $(\nu, \mu)$-th components of the covariant derivative of the 1-form $T$. The second expression denotes the $\nu$ component of the covariant derivative of the FUNCTION $T_{\mu},$ which is the $\mu$-th coordinate of the 1-form $T.$ In other words, $T=\sum T_i dx^i.$ I've edited my question.

Comment: In general the component of a tensor itself is not well defined under change of coordinate. What is the motivation of considering that?

Comment: I have a tensor $T$ which satisfies an equation of the form $\Delta T_{\mu\nu}= T_{\mu\nu}$ on a manifold. I know that $T$ vanishes in an open subset of the manifold, and I want to apply standard tools from analysis in $\mathbb{R}^n$ (namely a Carleman inquality) to prove that $T$ is identically zero. Since my equation is tensorial, I need to first fix a coordinate system and then show that each component is zero.

Comment: I think some parts of the formula in your link is not correct. (In particular, all equations has wrong summing indices, $\mu$ appears more than twice).

Comment: That Wolfram article is [wrong](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4684740/949989).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did the case for a $(0, 1)$ tensor $A = A_i$, it's

$$ (\Delta A)_i = \Delta (A_i) - g^{jk}\partial _k \Gamma_{ij}^l A_l - 2 g^{jk}\Gamma_{ij}^l A_{l,k} +g^{jk}\Gamma_{ik}^l \Gamma_{jl}^m A_m + g^{jk} \Gamma_{jk}^l \Gamma_{il}^m A_m$$

In general there is no hope that $(\Delta A)_i = \Delta (A_i)$, since the equations should be all coupled and the term $g^{jk}\partial _k \Gamma_{ij}^l A_l$ involves the curvature. If your manifold is something explicit, might be you can simplify the term though.